# Running OpenBSD 6.5; "rcctl start xenodm" does not start Xwindows, it returns "xenodm(ok)"

Tags: gnome, openbsd

I installed gnome today on OpenBSD 6.5. Since we no longer use startx, I did `rcctl enable xenodm`. There were no errors. Then I did `rcctl start xenodm`. The only response was one line of text: `xenodm(ok)`. 
Here is what I found in xenodm.log:

```
xenodm info (pid 90483): Starting
xenodm info (pid 90483): Starting X server on :0

X.Org X Server 1.19.7
Release Date: 2019-03-02
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: OpenBSD 6.5 amd64 
Current Operating System: OpenBSD JRW_OBSD.JRW 6.5 GENERIC.MP#2 amd64
Build Date: 13 April 2019  03:11:58PM

Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Aug 20 21:52:07 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/X11R6/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE)
```

I thought the `machdep.allowaperture-1` setting in /etc/sysctl.conf was deprecated, but do I need it anyway so I'm not getting `no screens`? My 6.5 install didn't even create a `sysctl.conf` file.

Comment: You seem to be using a custom kernel. Does it work with the default kernel? What is the output of `dmesg`? Are there any interesting errors in the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` log file mentioned in your post?

Comment: It's not a custom kernel; it's the basic iso from OpenBSD.org.

Comment: xenodm did not write to Xorg.0.log

Comment: Sorry, I mistook `JRW_OBSD.JRW` for the name of the kernel, but I assume it's your host's name. Are you able to test a more up to date version of the system? I can only find a reference about not setting `machdep.allowaperture` in a message to the `misc` and `tech` mailing lists dated in June 2019. https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-tech&m=156027567531231&w=2

Comment: The install was less than five weeks ago. I think it is the most up-to-date version. OpenBSD.org doesn't have a newer one.

Comment: I was thinking of a snapshot.

Comment: Without a `dmesg` there is no way to tell what hardware you are running and crucially if the video chipset/card was properly detected.